# Plots in TikZ don't work

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to do some plots using TikZ, however the following code doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (2.2,0) node[right] {$x$}; %
      \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,3.2) node[above] {$y$};%
      \draw plot (\x,{\x^2});%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

How to plot functions like `x \mapsto a^x (a > 0)`?

Edit: Thanks for the patch, however ploting `2^x` doesn't work, I get the following picture using Jakes answer:

[image]

Comment: Could you please change the image to not include a large white space on top? Also please describe your issue more precise. "Doesn't work" is not very descriptive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I work around this TikZ bug?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/how-can-i-work-around-this-tikz-bug)

Comment: Could you add the code you used to generate the image?

Comment: @Jake: I copied exactly your code from below.

Answer (score 5):

As Martin Scharrer pointed out, this is a bug that Hendrik Vogt has provided a patch for in his answer to the question [How can I work around this TikZ bug: (\x)^2 and \x^2 produce different results in TikZ plot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/how-can-i-work-around-this-tikz-bug/5531#5531)

On a side note: `tikz` loads `pgf` automatically, so you don't need to load it explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}%

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@scan@no@calculator#1(#2){%
    \patch@tikz(#2)%
    \expandafter\tikz@@scan@@no@calculator\expandafter#1\tikz@temp
    }
\def\patch@tikz(#1,#2){%
    {\expandafter\let\expandafter\save@tikz@plot@var\tikz@plot@var
     \expandafter\def\tikz@plot@var{(\save@tikz@plot@var)}%
     \xdef\tikz@temp@i{#1}%
     \xdef\tikz@temp@ii{#2}%
     }%
    \edef\tikz@temp{({\tikz@temp@i},{\tikz@temp@ii})}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[->] (-2.2,0) -- (2.2,0) node[right] {$x$}; %
      \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,3.2) node[above] {$y$};%
      \draw [domain=-2:2,orange] plot (\x,\x^2);
      \draw [domain=-2:2,blue] plot (\x,2^\x);%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz plot]

Comment: Is this that PGF bug for v2.1 (or was it v2.x)?

Comment: @Martin: Indeed, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. So this should be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks, however plotting 2^\x seems not to work

Comment: @user4011: It does for me, see the edited answer. Maybe you'se using an old version of TikZ?

Comment: @Jake: How to find out the tikz version? See my edit above

Comment: @user4011: Just add `\pgfversion` to your document just after `\begin{document}`, the version will then be shown in the document.

Comment: @Jake: `\pgfversion` gives 2.10

Comment: @user4011: That should work fine. Could you compile the file again after adding `\listfiles`, and then edit your question to include the list of used files that you can find near the end of the `.log` file?

Comment: The patch described above did not work for me when dealing with more complicated power functions; instead I used this alternative patch http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31791/14564