# custom function in pgf doesn't behave consistently

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is plotting exponential graphs a known source of bugs in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31775/is-plotting-exponential-graphs-a-known-source-of-bugs-in-tikz)

I want to use a custom function in pgf plots and in text, like in this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\def\frho(#1){pow(#1,(1/\fKappa))}%

% \pgfmathdeclarefunction{rho}{1}{%
%   \pgfmathparse{pow(#1,(1/\fKappa))}%
% }

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fKappa}{1.4}
\pgfmathparse{\frho(0.15)}$\rho(0.15) = \pgfmathresult$\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[name=upper,
                xmin=0,xmax=1,width=10cm,
                ymin=0,ymax=1,height=10cm,
                scale only axis,
                x dir=reverse,
                xlabel={$p$},
                ylabel={$\rho$}
                ]
    \addplot[domain=0.001:1,samples=50,smooth] {\frho(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The outcoming plot is correct, but the text result is not: the pdf says rho(0.15) = 3.84593. This happens with the `\def` variant as well as with the `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` variant. I don't think this might be caused by the limitations of `pow`, because one result is correct.

How can I fix this?

Comment: There's a bug in the `exp` function of `pgfmath`, which is used internally by the `pow` function. It's been fixed in the CVS version of `pgf`. If you don't want to update to the CVS version, you can just copy the relevant bit of code into your document: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31791/2552. The function works in pgfplots because it uses the `fpu` engine, which reimplements the `exp` function correctly.