# pgfplots: three dimensional plot with one variable as exponent?

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

In want to draw this function with pgfplots: f(x,y) = 1-(1-(1+y)^(-x))/x*y. When compiling, I get some error message about `z buffer reoderings`. I already played around a bit and ist seems to me the problem is that one variable (x) is in the exponent. So I broke it down to the simple function (1+y)^(x) and the problem still arises. Is there a way to plot this function type with pgfplots or is it just not possible?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[surf] {(1+y)^(x)};
%\addplot3[surf] {1-(1-(1+y)^(-x))/(x*y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Edit: Just to show what it should look like:
[image]

Comment: Possibly related to: [Is plotting exponential graphs a known source of bugs in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31775/is-plotting-exponential-graphs-a-known-source-of-bugs-in-tikz)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of a divide by zero in your original function at `x=0,y=0`, which yields a `nan` that throws PGFplots off track. You can remove `nan`s by adding the key `restrict z to domain*=-inf:inf`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[restrict z to domain=-inf:inf]
\addplot3[surf] {1-(1-(1+y)^(-x))/(x*y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the `dividing by zero` problem and already tried to set `xmin,ymin` in the axis options accordingly as I only need positive values. However, this just gave me more error messages. I guess, I'll just plot it another way.

Comment: Note that `xmin,ymin` will still cause the problem: they only restrict the axis range, not the range in which samples will be taken. Consider using `samples=min:max` and `samples y=min:max` to reduce the sampled range.

Answer (score 5):

You could rewrite the function as `exp((x)*ln((1+y)))`:

[image]

Your original function can be written as

```
\addplot3[surf] {1-(1-(exp((-x)*ln(1+y))))/(x*y)};
```

and yields:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot3[surf] {exp((x)*ln((1+y)))};
  %\addplot3[surf] {1-(1-(1+y)^(-x))/(x*y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps tell me how to change my original function accordingly? Logarithms are not my strong point.

Comment: @meep.meep: Done, but that is more of a math question than a TeX question.

Comment: I'll accept Jakes answer because it has additional informaton on how to restrict a domain. But thank you for your help.