# As my exponentials in TikZ plot a parabolic style function, do I install CVS version, and how?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, installing, graphs

I'm very new to LaTeX.

I have read [Is plotting exponential graphs a known source of bugs in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31775/is-plotting-exponential-graphs-a-known-source-of-bugs-in-tikz) and implemented the code Jake supplied and this fixed the current problem. Thanks Jake :).

On this same page and in other forums people have mentioned a CVS install, should I take this step? I don't really know what it is as I use MikTex 2.9 and it says TikZ is current, yet my exponential graphs are the only one's that break. I am a math teacher/tutor and trying to use LaTeX for all my documents now, it's a big learning curve but the results are worth it. So will a CVS install be of greater benefit? And if so, how do I install this with the MikTeX Manager, or else wise.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot install TiKZ CVS version with MikTeX Package Manager but you can add it in your local tex tree. MikTeX's manual chapter [Integrating Local Additions](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/localadditions.html) explains how to add and manage your own packages.

You can download CVS version from sourceforge but also can find some TDS builds at [Altermundus web page](http://www.altermundus.com/pages/builds/index.html) or [tlcontrib](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/ruid=2867843737/action=view/id=632)

Comment: @Therese You can also get the CVS version here : `http://perso.mines-albi.fr/~gaborit/latex/tikz-pgf.html`