# Superellipse filled with a color

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill, shapes, tikz-shape

I would like to create a [`superellipse`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) shape. I found the following question "[How do I make a superellipse node shape in tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87740/how-do-i-make-a-superellipse-node-shape-in-tikz)" with [@Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87784/263552) that does indeed produce a superellipse. Unfortunately I would like to `fill` the superellipse with a color and it does not work by adding `fill=blue` for example to Jake's superellipse node parameters.

```
\node [fill=blue,minimum width=4cm, minimum height=2cm,
 superellipse, superellipse parameter=1.5] (a) {};
```

I don't know if this is due to the fact that it is a node shape. This is not necessary in my case of use and a `path` in the shape of a superellipse is enough for me. In fact I am looking for more or less the equivalent of a

```
\fill [blue] (0,0) circle [x radius=2cm, y radius=1cm];
```

but for a `superellipse`.

Moreover the code in the referred answer was written more than 9 years ago, maybe there is a way to do things more efficiently today, following the improvements of tikz etc.

Comment: Hmm. Try (in the cited @Jake's answer) to change the `\pgfusepath{stroke}` to `\pgfusepath{stroke, fill}`. I am not at the computer now, so I can't test it....

Comment: You are doing the correct thing by creating a new question. Never add sub questions to old question - just link to them as you do. What could be better is to add some compilable code instead of fragments. - e.g. just with the circle so people can see your documentclass and packages.

Comment: @Rmano: It works indeed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
  sx(\t)= a*cos(\t r)^(2/n);
  sy(\t)= b*sin(\t r)^(2/n);
  a=1;
  b=1;
  n=4;
}]
\draw[fill=green, variable=\t, domain=0:pi/2] plot ({sx(\t)},{sy(\t)}) -- plot({-sx(pi/2-\t)},{sy(pi/2-\t)}) -- plot({-sx(\t)},{-sy(\t)}) -- plot({sx(pi/2-\t)},{-sy(pi/2-\t)}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Green superellipse]

Edit: Here is an alternative way to draw the same:

```
\draw[fill=green, variable=\t]
  plot[domain=0:pi/2] ({sx(\t)},{sy(\t)}) -- 
  plot[domain=pi/2:0] ({-sx(\t)},{sy(\t)}) --
  plot[domain=0:pi/2] ({-sx(\t)},{-sy(\t)}) --
  plot[domain=pi/2:0] ({sx(\t)},{-sy(\t)}) -- cycle;
```

Comment: Wow, this is (almost) perfect. And much simpler than Jake's code. A little typo though, I think. It should always be `sx(t)` first, `sy(t)` second (with the right sign each time). Your 2nd and 4th plot have inverted sx and sy (it doesn't show if `a = b`). If you correct it I will validate the answer.

Comment: No - it is not a typo. I am using the fact that `sin` and `cos` is `pi/2` out of phase. If you prefer, you can invert the domain and then use `sx(pi/2-\t)` instead of `sy(\t)` to get the correct orientation (draw direction).

Comment: I understand but there is also `a` in `sx(t)` and `b` in `sy(t)`. If you reverse the 2 for some points it still gives a superellipse for `a=b` but it gives a weird shape for `a different from b`. Take your first code and put `a=1` and `b=2` for example and you will see the result.

Comment: @Xorios: You are correct - I have corrected the code.