# My Geogebra graph breaks with multiple errors

Tags: tikz-pgf

Updated:

I want a graph that drops vertically about 1/3 of the way across and 2/3 across. When I input this into Texmaker it has multiple errors including

```
Dimension too large
Package PGF Math Error: I cannot calculate the logarithm of '0,0' 
(in '{2(0,0)^(3/2)-3(0,0)+1.4}').
```

Even the standalone doesn't work, so is it a package problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=4.34618291761148cm,y=4.205741626794257cm]
\draw[->,color=black] (-0.1,0) -- (1.97,0);
\foreach \x in {,1}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.81,0.02) node [anchor=south west] { Order Quantity};
\draw[->,color=black] (0,-0.14) -- (0,2);
\foreach \y in {,1}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
\clip(-0.1,-0.14) rectangle (1.97,2);
\draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:1.9707826086956564] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+2});
\draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:1.9707826086956564] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+1.7});
\draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:1.9707826086956564] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+1.4});
\draw[line width=1.2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:0.6666666666666666] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+2});
\draw[line width=1.2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.6666666666666666:1.3333333333333333] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+1.7});
\draw[line width=1.2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=1.3333333333333333:1.9707826086956564] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+1.4});
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (0.67,1.09)-- (0.67,0.79);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.33,0.78)-- (1.33,0.48);
\draw (1.01,0.03) node[anchor=north west] {$Q^*$};
\draw (-0.06,0.79) node[anchor=north west] {$C^*$};
\draw (0.01,1.99) node[anchor=north west] {Average Cost per Unit Time};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{document}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because the `domain` for the plots is set to start at `0`, where the logarithm isn't defined. Just set the `domain`s to start at `0.01` or some other small value:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=4.34618291761148cm,y=4.205741626794257cm]
\draw[->,color=black] (-0.1,0) -- (1.97,0);
\foreach \x in {,1}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.81,0.02) node [anchor=south west] { Order Quantity};
\draw[->,color=black] (0,-0.14) -- (0,2);
\foreach \y in {,1}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
\clip(-0.1,-0.14) rectangle (1.97,2);
\draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:1.9707826086956564] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+2});
\draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:1.9707826086956564] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+1.7});
\draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:1.9707826086956564] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+1.4});
\draw[line width=1.2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:0.6666666666666666] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+2});
\draw[line width=1.2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.6666666666666666:1.3333333333333333] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+1.7});
\draw[line width=1.2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=1.3333333333333333:1.9707826086956564] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+1.4});
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (0.67,1.09)-- (0.67,0.79);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.33,0.78)-- (1.33,0.48);
\draw (1.01,0.03) node[anchor=north west] {$Q^*$};
\draw (-0.06,0.79) node[anchor=north west] {$C^*$};
\draw (0.01,1.99) node[anchor=north west] {Average Cost per Unit Time};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason, the answer you posted gives me the exact same problem. Says: Dimension too large.

It references these lines:

\draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:1.9707826086956564] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+2});
\draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:1.9707826086956564] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+1.7});
\draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:1.9707826086956564] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+1.4});
\draw[line width=1.2pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:0.6666666666666666] plot(\x,{2*(\x)^(3/2)-3*(\x)+2});

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a full minimal example document (starting from `\documentclass`)?

Comment: I tried using just the standalone that you posted and that had the same problem that it had when in my full document. I don't understand it since it obviously worked for you?

Comment: @DannyBland: Ah yes, sorry, it works for me because I'm using the CVS version of TikZ, where a bug in the math library has been fixed. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31775/is-plotting-exponential-graphs-a-known-source-of-bugs-in-tikz for the fix

Comment: @DannyBland: Your updated MWE works.  I have TeXLive 12.