# How to write ‎y = (x / 6) ‎^ {3 / ‎7} in TikZ format to plot its graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

How to write `y=(x/6)‎^{3/‎7}` in TikZ format to plot its graph in the following code?

```
‎\documentclass{article}‎
‎‎\usepackage{tikz‎}‎ 
‎\begin{document}‎‎
‎‎\begin{tikzpicture}‎
‎\draw ‎[‎smooth,‎samples=100‎,domain=0:‎‎2‎‎] ‎plot(\x,‎‎‎‎‎‎‎{(\x)‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎});‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎‎
‎\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the $\exp(\ln(x))$ form:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:10] plot(\x,{exp(3*ln(\x/6)/7)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Doesn't work in 0, of course...

Answer (score 11):

This answer is more of a "did you possibly mean a plot together with its axis?"-answer.

If so, you might be interested in `pgfplots`; a package built on top of tikz. It can sample with higher accuracy and a considerably higher data range, accepts a very similar syntax as tikz, scales the plot to some prescribed width/height, automatically computes ticks, comes with interfaces like `xlabel=the x axis`, and is highly customable.

Here is your example with pgfplots:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot [smooth,samples=100,domain=0:10] {(x/6)^(3/7)};
% same as:
%\addplot [smooth,samples=100,domain=0:10] plot(x,{(x/6)^(3/7)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that my solution suffers from a bug in TikZ: 0^(3/7) should be 0. I have just fixed it in pgf cvs, will become part of the next stable. The current solution excludes it because it computed 0^x = nan.

Answer (score 7):

With *tkz-fct* or with *Tikz + gnuplot* the syntaxes are different. gnuplot needs strange notations.

```
 1) exp(3*log(x/6)/7 log signifies ln
 2) (x/6)**(3./7) ** is used for ^ and 3./7 is used to divide with real numbers
```

The results are the same in each case.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
 \begin{document}  

     \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=2] 
      \tkzGrid 
      \tkzAxeXY 
   %  \tkzFct[color=red,thick,domain=0.001:10,samples=500]{exp(3*log(x/6)/7)}
      \tkzFct[color=red,thick,domain=0:10,samples=200]{(x/6)**(3./7)}
     \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

with Tikz and gnuplot :

```
  \draw[color=red,domain=0:10,samples=200]    plot[id=x]   function{(x/6)**(3./7)} ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

(I changed domain a bit)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [smooth,samples=100,domain=0.01:10] plot(\x,{(\x/6)^(3/7)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @lohann: Thanks for your answer, but why isn't y=0, when x=0?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the `pow` function for numbers between `0` and `1`.   Probably the same bug as http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31775/15925

Comment: Yeah, looks like a bug... :(

Answer (score 3):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{algebraic,unit=0.5cm,labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle,labelsep=2pt,plotpoints=100}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(11,2)
    \psparametricplot{0}{10}{t|(t/6)^(3/7)}
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(11,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks PSTricks, I don't need to use \ in the expression.

Comment: Could you please tell me why the two solutions above (using TikZ and pstricks) are different? In other words, by using TikZ, why isn't y=0, when x=0?

Comment: @Sisabe: Because there might be  [a bug](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/c/3/b/d/1194985428453820625bug_nicu_buculei_01.svg.med.png) in TikZ (for this case).

Comment: @PSTikZ good observation. I have fixed the bug in TikZ CVS; will become part of the next stable.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: OK. Thanks for fixing it.