# How to plot x^(1/3)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I tried to export my Geogebra graphs into tikz-code. In General it works fine, but plot x^1/3 doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{ccqqqq}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\definecolor{qqttcc}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.8}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw [color=cqcqcq,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt, xstep=1.0cm,ystep=1.0cm] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
\draw[->,color=black] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
\foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\draw[->,color=black] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
\foreach \y in {-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
\clip(-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[color=qqttcc, smooth,samples=100,domain=-4.0:4.0] plot(\x,{(\x)*(\x)*(\x)});
\draw[color=ccqqqq, smooth,samples=100,domain=-4.0:4.0] plot(\x,{((\x))^(1/(3))});
\draw [color=qqttcc](2.06,4.18) node[anchor=north west] {$f(x)=x^3$};
\draw [color=ccqqqq](2.06,1.18) node[anchor=north west] {$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=qqttcc] (-1.74,-7.16) node {$f$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> Error line 21: !Missing number, treated as zero.

So plot has problems with the negative x I suppose, but I don't know.
Any help would be great! I *googled* it for nearly 1 hour - but no real answers.

As suggestet it rotated and mirrored the graph - works great!:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{ccqqqq}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\definecolor{qqttcc}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.8}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw [color=cqcqcq,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt, xstep=1.0cm,ystep=1.0cm] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
\draw[->,color=black] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
\foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize \x};
\draw[->,color=black] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
\foreach \y in {-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize \y};
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize 0};
\clip(-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[color=qqttcc, smooth,samples=100,domain=-4.0:4.0] plot(\x,{(\x)*(\x)*(\x)});
\begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw[rotate=90, color=ccqqqq, smooth,samples=100,domain=-4.0:4.0] plot(\x,{(\x)*(\x)*(\x)});
\end{scope}
\draw [color=qqttcc](2.06,4.00) node[anchor=north west] {$f(x)=x^3$};
\draw [color=ccqqqq](2.06,1.00) node[anchor=north west] {$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=qqttcc] (-1.74,-7.16) node {f};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/pgf-math-function-to-compute-cube-root).

Comment: The elegant way would be to plot $y=x^3$ but reflected across the line $y=x$. That way you never need to compute a cube root, so computations are faster and, more importantly, more accurate.

Comment: And how do i do that?

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay I tried `\draw[color=ccqqqq, smooth,samples=50,domain=0.0001:4.0] plot(\x, {(\x)^(1/3)});` with the same code as [jojo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/40880/jojo) but the shape of the curve is completely wrong for values less than `1.0`.

Comment: ah ok, I understand that with `\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary {fixedpointarithmetic}` and the key `fixed point arithmetic` added to the picture, it now works. The failure of naked `pgfmath` on this one is spectacular!

Comment: The best way is the parametric plot in Herbert's answer. It is essentially the same as plotting `y=x^3` but without the extra transformation. The steep slope of `y=x^{1/3}` requires high sampling in the `x` variable, and high accuracy. But that is not a problem with plotting `y=x^3`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write ‎y = (x / 6) ‎^ {3 / ‎7} in TikZ format to plot its graph?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105566/how-to-write-y-x-6-3-7-in-tikz-format-to-plot-its-graph)

Comment: Using `f(x) = x / abs(x) (abs(x))^0.333` seems to work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm sure we've answered this before, but here's a solution using [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots).

When plotting cube root functions it is useful to know that many programs (including the wonderful `pgfplots` package) use logarithms to plot them. As such, you have to be careful with the domain.

In the code below, I have plotted the function

```
x/|x|*(|x|)^(1/3)
```

which ensures that the function is plotted for the entire domain.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% set the arrows as stealth fighters
\tikzset{>=stealth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    axis lines=center,
    axis line style=<->]
    \addplot[<->] expression[domain=-10:10,samples=100]{x/abs(x)*abs(x)^(1/3)}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `x/abs(x)*abs(x)^(1/3)` is a genius expression that is continuous but not differentiable. +1!

Comment: @Marienplatz thanks! I'm afraid I can't take any credit for it, though :) It's a trick I got from somewhere else.

Comment: Interestingly it also works for `samples=11`, i.e. for x=0.

Answer (score 18):

With PSTricks.

### Option 1 (with Postfix Notation)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-2.5)(4,3)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-2.5)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \pstVerb{/power 1 3 div def}
    \psplot[plotpoints=1000,linecolor=blue]{-3}{3}{x dup 0 lt {neg power exp neg} {power exp} ifelse}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Option 2 (with Infix Notation)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-2.5)(4,3)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-2.5)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[plotpoints=1000,linecolor=blue,algebraic]{-3}{3}{IfTE(x<0,-(-x)^(1/3),x^(1/3))}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 3 (with Rotation)

This is the last resort only for children. The right leaf is rotated 180 degrees about the origin to get the left leaf.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{plotpoints=1000}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+10}{19}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-2.5)(4,3)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-2.5)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \def\right{\psplot[linecolor=blue,algebraic]{0}{3}{x^(1/3)}}%
    \rput{\i}{\right}\right
    %\def\right{\psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{3}{x 1 3 div exp}}%
    %\rput{180}{\right}\right
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 4 (with Parametric Plot)

Please see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144460/232373) answer.

### Option 5 (with Implicit Plot)

With an extra bug.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-2.5)(4,3)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-2.5)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psplotImp[linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.2,algebraic](-3,-1.5)(3,1.5){y^3-x}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The bug can be hidden by clipping the unwanted curves.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-2.5)(4,3)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-2.5)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none,dimen=monkey](!-3 3 1 3 div exp neg)(!3 3 1 3 div exp)}
        \psplotImp[linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.1,algebraic](-4,-3)(5,4){y^3-x}
    \endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 6 (with swapaxes)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-2.5)(4,3)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-2.5)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psplot[linecolor=red,algebraic,plotpoints=1000,swapaxes]{3 1 3 div exp neg}{3 1 3 div exp}{x^3}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

use the parametric form:  x=t³ and y=t:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-2.5)(4,3)
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-2.5)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=blue,algebraic]{-1.5}{1.5}{t^3|t}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or the implicit form `y³-x=0`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-3.5,-2.5)(4,3)
  \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,ticksize=0 4pt]{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-2.5)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psplotImp[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,algebraic](-4,-3)(4,3){y^3-x}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

IEEE math usually gives NaN (not a number) for `x^a` when `x ≤ 0` and `a` is not integer.

You can draw `x^{1/3}` for `x` in `[0.00001:4]` and `-(-x)^{1/3}` for `x` in `[-4:-0.00001]`

Comment: Why do you reference to IEEE math?

Comment: Is not it underlying pgf math?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use [gnuplot to compute the 1/3 floating point expressions](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html) with `-shell-escape` enabled and `gnuplot` installed.

The idea is to evaluate `1/3` first similar to making atleast one numerator or denominator floating point value like this `1./3` or `1.0/3`. Note: `sgn(x)` is Sign function (-1 if x < 0; 0 if x = 0; 1 if x > 0). One might need more samples of points to get a refined plot. Here are some examples with packages that use gnuplot.

With [tkz-fct](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-fct)

```
\documentclass[preview=true,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\tkzInit[xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2]
\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[color=red]{sgn(x)*(abs(x)**(1./3))}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With [gnuplottex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex)

```
\documentclass[preview=true,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{gnuplottex} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
  set grid
   set samples 1000
   set xlabel '$x$'
  set ylabel '$ x^{\frac{1}{3}} $'
  plot [-2:2] [-2:2] sgn(x)*(abs(x)**(1./3)) title '$ x^{\frac{1}{3}} $' linetype 1 linewidth 3
\end{gnuplot} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

With [pgfplots](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) and even pure [tikz](http://www.ctan.org/topic/pgf-tikz) can be used.

```
\documentclass[preview=true,border=2pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$x^{\frac{1}{3}}$,grid=major,enlargelimits=false]
\addplot [domain=-2:2,samples=1000,red,no markers] gnuplot[id=poly]{sgn(x)*(abs(x)**(1./3)) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw[dashed,gray!30](-3,-3)grid(3,3); %this creates the grid you see;
                                       %dashed, gives the dashed lines
                                       %gray!30, gives a gray color be dim by factor of 30.
\draw[<->](-3,0)--(3,0)node[below right]{$x$}; %this is the x-axis
\draw[<->](0,-3)--(0,3)node[above right]{$y$}; %this is the y-axis
\foreach \x in {-2,-1,1,2} %this starts a while loop with "\x" touching -2,-1,1,2 then ends.
    \draw(\x,2pt)--(\x,-2pt)node[below]{\footnotesize{$\x$}}; %this is what I want the foreach
                                                              %loop to do until it reaches the semi-colon.
                                                              %this is what gives the tick marks and numbers on the axis
\foreach \x in {-2,-1,1,2} %same as before but for the y-axis
    \draw(2pt,\x)--(-2pt,\x)node[left]{\footnotesize{$\x$}};
\draw[<->,domain=-1.442249:1.442249,samples=100]plot({\x*\x*\x},\x); %where x^3=2 when x=1.442249'ish
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=.75]
    \draw [line width=0.3pt,pink](-3,-2) grid (3,2);
    \draw[>=latex,->,color=black,] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
    \foreach \x in {-2,2}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
    \draw[>=latex,->,color=black] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
    \foreach \y in {}
    \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
    %\draw[color=black] (0pt,-1pt) node[below left] {\footnotesize $0$};
    \node at (3,0) [right] {\small $x$};
    \node at (0,2) [above ] {\small $y$};
    \draw[line width=1pt,red,domain=-1.442249:1.442249,samples=200]plot({\x*\x*\x},\x); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 0):

The arc of the curve of a polynomial of order 3 is a cubic Bézier spline.

For example, the curve of x^(1/3) on [-8,8] is the cubic Bézier spline corresponding to the points (-8,-2), (8,-2/3), (-8,2/3) and (8,2).

Here is that cubic spline drawn with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale = 0.7]
\draw [->] (-8.5,0) -- (8.5,0) ; 
\draw [->] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5) ; 
\draw [red] (-8,-2) .. controls (8,-0.666) and (-8,0.666) .. (8,2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the code with tikz]

Here is the code with `pstricks`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\psset{unit=7mm}
\begin{pspicture}(-9,-3)(9,3)
\psline{->}(-8.5,0)(8.5,0)
\psline{->}(0,-2.5)(0,2.5)
\psbezier[linecolor=red](-8,-2)(8,-0.666)(-8,0.666)(8,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the code with pstricks]