# how to draw y=(x-1)^(1/3)

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to plot `(x-1)^(1/3)` just by `tikzpicture` on grid of coordinate axes not by use of `pspicture`.
(In this post [How to plot x^(1/3)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144454/how-to-plot-x1-3), used as `pspicture`)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=.75]
        \draw [line width=0.3pt,pink](-3,-3) grid (3,3);
        \draw[>=latex,->,color=black,] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
        \foreach \x in {-1,1}
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
        \draw[>=latex,->,color=black] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
        \foreach \y in {}
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
        %\draw[color=black] (0pt,-1pt) node[below left] {\footnotesize $0$};
        \node at (3,0) [right] {\small $x$};
        \node at (0,3) [above ] {\small $y$};
        \draw [line width=1pt,red,samples=200] plot[domain=-3:3](\x,{((\x)-1)^(1/3)});
        \draw [fill=blue] (0,0) circle (3pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You need to show what you have tried. As always - include a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: I count three different examples on that page that use only tikz-pgf.

Comment: Yes you are right.But none of them used a grid of coordinate axes and cannot  resize the shape.

Comment: from my solution on that link, can you use `    \addplot[<->] expression[domain=-10:10,samples=100]{(x-1)/abs(x-1)*abs(x-1)^(1/3)}; `