# Reversing a path in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

When I use `\path plot function {x^2};` in tikz, it plots it left-to-right (the default domain is `-5:5`).  This is annoying, because, for example, one cannot pile on `-- plot function {x^2 + 1} -- cycle;` and then fill the whole thing; it doesn't fill the obvious cycle, but rather the self-intersecting one going between opposite corners as it "returns carriage", so to speak.

Is there some way to get `plot function` to generate points in the reverse order?  Alternatively, is there some way of getting tikz to draw a path in the reverse order the points were specified?  (This last one is of more general utility, since the orientation of a path is used a lot.)

Comment: You can specify the domain as `5:-5`?

Comment: @Peter: sadly, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use PGFplots for plotting your functions, the paths will be reversed and connected appropriately by using `stack plots=y` in the `axis` options and issuing `\closedcycle` after the second plot:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    stack plots=y,
    hide axis
]
\addplot [draw=orange,thick]{x^2};
\addplot [draw=orange, thick, fill=yellow] {1} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If all you want is the filled path, you can disable the axes by using `hide axis`.

Comment: I really should be using pgfplots, eh?  Does it allow me to outsource to gnuplot and, if so, does `\closedcycle` work as expected?

Comment: It sure does! Just use `\addplot gnuplot {x**2};` instead of `\addplot {x^2};`, and the calculations will be done by gnuplot. The `\closedcycle` works exactly as before.

Comment: Well, then it looks like you've answered my question!

Answer (score 7):

With the current implementation of plot function, I don't think it is possible since pgf reads sequencially the file output by gnuplot. Since gnuplot computes values of the function from the lowest value of x to the highest value, the reverse order is not possible (see file pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (I may have missed a gnuplot option to do so).

However, you can achieve what you want with the pgf math engine like in the following, reversing the bounds of the domain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]
  \fill plot (\x,\x^2) -- plot[domain=5:-5] (\x,\x^2 + 1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: this is my first contrib to tex.se. Hope it is formatted ok.

Comment: It gives an `x^3` plot when implemented :) Your format is A-OK by the way.

Comment: @percusse: It's actually a `x*abs(x)` plot. That's a bug in TikZ that's been around for a long time. Hendrik Vogt posted a fix at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/how-can-i-work-around-this-tikz-bug/5531#5531

Comment: It's good to know that reversing the domain works when tikz is in charge, but there are good reasons to use gnuplot, e.g. for computationally expensive functions.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can force Gnuplot compute the path in the order you want. 
The idea is to use Gnuplot's parametric curve representation.

In the following example (in the %% Good section, the %% Bad section is just here to show what happens if the trick is not used), I draw the first curve normally, and the second one using the trick.
Each value of the parameter t which lives between 0 and 1 is sent to the desired interval (here [2,-1] in that order) using the barycentric formula : x = (1-t) *2 + t *(-1)

More generally, if you want to send [0,1] on to [a,b] starting with b you just use
(1-t)*b + t*a.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

%% Requires Gnuplot !

%% Functions definition
\newcommand{\funcf}[1]{(#1)**2)}   % it is wise to always put the #1 argument between ()
\newcommand{\funcg}[1]{1+(#1)**2)}

%% Bad 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill
        plot[domain=-1:2, id=funcf] function {\funcf{x}}
        --  
        plot[domain=2:-1, id=funcgbad] function {\funcg{x}} % inverting boundaries does *NOT* work with Gnuplot
        -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}


%% Good 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill
        plot[domain=-1:2, id=funcf] function {\funcf{x}}
        --  
        plot[domain=0:1, parametric, id=funcggood] function {(1-t)*2+t*(-1),\funcg{(1-t)*2+t*(-1)}} 
        -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```