# Using pgfplots with a0poster

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, debugging, plot, posters

I want to use tikz/pgf to plot some graphs in a poster done with [a0poster](http://andreas.welcomes-you.com/projects/a0poster/). That is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel=lambda, ylabel=int]
    \addplot[blue] table [mark=none, col sep=comma, trim cells=true]{data.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here's what it should look like, compiled in DIN-A4 (standard paper size):

[image: tikz-plot]

This is what happens with a0poster (never mind about the background):

[image: tikz_in_a0poster]

Apart from the screwed up labeling and positioning (which might be fixed), there are curves in all the wrong places. The frame has 3 curvy corners and the single data points are connected by way too big arcs. That's what makes the hairs, here is it in detail:

[image: tikz_in_a0poster_detail]

> Well, do you have an idea of how to make pgfplot work correctly with
>   a0poster?

(Or, if not, which poster packages are compatible with pgfplot? It would hurt to port the finished poster layout to another package, but if there's no other solution, then that's the pill to swallow.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your image links seem to be broken. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again. You apparently deleted the URL lines at the end, which makes the link entries useless.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Nice workaround, I was not aware of that. Thank you.

Comment: Could this be a driver issue? Usually, PGF will auto-detect the latex/dvips combination which appears to be required for a0poster. But perhaps somehow the auto-detection failed. Have you tried any other tikz pictures? The correct driver seems to be `def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvips.def}` before loading tikz

Comment: Note that the fallback solution could also be: generate EPS images of your pgfplots images (preferrably in the correct sizes such that no rescaling is required) - then import these graphics into your poster. Switching to another poster layout should be unnecessary.

Comment: And one further hint: this question is unrelated to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/how-can-i-work-around-this-tikz-bug .

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Nope, seems not to be a driver issue. I tried all of this list: http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg Some of them give the distorted plot, some of them totally scramble the layout, the plot was somewhere off the page. The workaround for me so far was indeed including externally generated pictures of the plot. However, I love how neat plots by LaTeX integrate in any document and would, at least in the long run, like to get this feature running with posters.

Comment: @Boffin sounds reasonable. Perhaps I need to get a0poster running on my system (I failed when I tried yesterday).

Answer (score 1):

I have used the `beamerposter` package for my poster some time ago. You can define your own style and it looks really nice on glossy paper. I did a little bit of `pgfplot` testing and it seems to work pretty OK. One thing you have to modify or create is your own theme style file. You can get the standard ones from [here](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php) and modify it accordingly.

Comment: @Boffin Much to my stupidity, `beamerposter` uses `beamer` which has a native support to `TikZ/PGF` and hence to `pgfplots`.