# Incorrect evaluation of expression?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I work around this TikZ bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/how-can-i-work-around-this-tikz-bug)

I am plotting points on function f(x)=1-x^2/2+x^4/16. Obviously f(x)=-f(x), but PGF does not think so.

[image: rendering of the plot]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikz{
    \draw[very thin, gray] (-2,0) grid (2,2);
    \draw[->] (-2.2,0) -- (2.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-.2) -- (0,2.2) node[right] {$y$};
        \def\wExpr{1-.5*(\x^2)+(1/16.)*(\x^4)}     %%%%% <<<
        \foreach\x in {-1.9,-1.3,-.8,-.2,.4,.9,1.5,2.0}{
            \fill (\x,{\wExpr}) circle (2pt);
        }
    }
\end{document}
```

What am I missing?

**PS:** I am able to work around it with `abs` around the exponentiation, but why does this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use it this way:

```
\def\wExpr{1-.5*((\x)^2)+(1/16.)*((\x)^4)}
```

Comment: Calling it a bug might be a bit harsh. I would assume that `\foreach` just performs string replacements, and `-1.9^2` is -3.61, as it should be.

Comment: ok, you are right, I'll fix the bug :-)

Comment: It is a bug that's been around for some time. Matthew Leingang posted a fix for it at [How Can I Work Around this TikZ Bug](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/how-can-i-work-around-this-tikz-bug/5531#5531).

Comment: no, Mikael is right! `-2^2=-4` is from the mathematical definition  correct. if the minus should be part of the 2 we have to write `(-2)^2=4`

Comment: @Herbert: But `x^2=4` for `x=-2`, and that's what the OP correctly expected. In the problem the variable should not be interpreted as a string of characters, but as an entity.

Comment: @Jake, ok understood