# draw plot \x^2, sign error

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I try to plot quadratic fonction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
bad, negative square equal...negative!


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot (\x,\x^2/4/1.0);
\end{tikzpicture}

good
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot (\x,\x*\x/4/1.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I found a solution, but why this surprising result?
Is there a way to use the square function?

Comment: I think this question has been asked before, perhaps by Peter Grill...

Comment: See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/how-can-i-work-around-this-tikz-bug-x2-and-x2-produce-different-results-i

Comment: I see, It's ok. It's exactly the same interrogation. Can you close it?