# How does TikZ parse powers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I was often stumbling upon (and correcting by hand) an IMHO rather surprising behavior of Ti*k*Z: powers are parsed in an unconventional way. Look at the MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=symb]
  \draw plot[variable=\x,domain=-1:1] (\x,{\x^2});
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=south] at (symb.north) {$x\verb|^|2$};
 % 
 \begin{scope}[xshift=2.5cm,local bounding box=pow]
 \draw[dotted] plot[variable=\x,domain=-1:1] (\x,{pow(\x,2)});
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=south] at (pow.north) {$\texttt{pow}(x,2)$};
 % 
 \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm,local bounding box=star]
 \draw[dashed] plot[variable=\x,domain=-1:1] (\x,{\x*\x});
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=south] at (star.north) {$x*x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The left/solid plot shows `x^2`, and naively I would expect it to coincide with `pow(x,2)` and `x*x`, but it doesn't. Rather, for negative `x`, the plot also grows in the negative direction.

On the other hand, pgfplots seems to correct for this, even/also (but not only) when one uses `declare function`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=\x^2;}]
 \begin{axis}[width=4cm,title={pgfplots}]
 \addplot[domain=-1:1] {f(x)};
 \end{axis}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm,yshift=1cm,local bounding box=tikz]
 \draw plot[variable=\x,domain=-1:1] (\x,{f(\x)});
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=south] at (tikz.north) {Ti\emph{k}Z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Naively, I'd expect the plots having the same qualitative shape (modulo adjustments of length scales made by `pgfplots`, of course). So `pgfplots` and Ti*k*Z seem to interpret the same function differently.

**Question**: Why is that? Is there a simple way to make Ti*k*Z produce the expected output (i.e. `x^2` is nonnegative)?

**NOTE**: @circumscribe made me aware of [this earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/how-can-i-work-around-this-tikz-bug-x2-and-x2-produce-different-results-i?noredirect=1&lq=1). Apart from the comparison to pgfplots, this post does not add anything to the story, and in any case most likely the only viable answer is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125896/121799). So I will certainly not object to this question being closed as a duplicate of [this earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/how-can-i-work-around-this-tikz-bug-x2-and-x2-produce-different-results-i?noredirect=1&lq=1). (I did search for earlier questions, but was under the impression they should contain parse in the title, which is why I didn't find it.)

Comment: interestingly! with `f(\x)=\x*\x` works fine ...

Comment: @Zarko Sure. This is what I did in all my answers so far (where that mattered).

Comment: also work correctly if you enclose variable in parenthesis: `f(\x)=(\x)^2`. it seem that negative values of variable `pgfplots` and pure `tikz` treats differently

Comment: @Zarko Thanks! Yes. The thing is that pgfplots does not require these brackets, which is why added the comparison. (But you are right, I could or even should have added the bracket example as well. )

Comment: Happens also for `x^4`...

Comment: @Rmano Yes, sure. For all even powers.

Comment: That's really strange. In `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex`  it seems that `\x^2` is the same as `pow(\x,2)` with very high precedence...: `\pgfmathdeclareoperator{^}{pow}     {2}{infix}{900}`

Comment: @Rmano I guess that the sign does not get squared, i.e. the parser sets the brackets not in the way one may expect it to.

Comment: Yep. My guess of the problem is that when going through the function calculation, the value of `\x` is *first* substituted with the number and *then* parsed as a math expression, I mean: for `\x`=-1, `plot` first substitutes `\x` with `-1`, and then computes `-1^2` which is, correctly, -1. The problem is that you should always surround values with parenthesis when substituting...
That reminds me the classic problem with `#define VAR -1` in `C`.

Comment: @Rmano I agree with all that. And this is what I did in many answers so far. My question is more whether there is a reason for that. Since pgfplots behaves differently, I guess that at least Christian Feuersänger noticed that and changed this. (I know of course that the pgfplots parser works a bit different, which is why you can use `f(x)` instead of `f(\x)`. ) To me it is simply strange that `\x^2` and `pow(\x,2)` are not equivalent.

Comment: So, for negative values, `x^2` is computed as `-|x|^2`? arrrrhhh

Comment: @marmot may be `TikZ` took `BODMAS` very strictly than it should be ;)

Comment: In any case, avoid all formats which allows floating point exponents, since they are implemented as exp(2*log(\x)).

Comment: [@marmot why not even powers too?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469747/how-does-tikz-parse-powers#comment1182772_469747)

Comment: @manooooh What I meant to say is that the parsing is unfortunate for all even powers, because the result of the parsing `x^n` is `sign(x)*pow(abs(x),n)`, where `n`  is the (integer) power. For odd `n` this is what one might expect, for even `n` it may be called unexpected.

Comment: @marmot: Have you seen the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5400/156366)? I have no idea if it's helpful or if the patch that's mentioned in the second answer (still) works.

Comment: @Circumscribe Thanks! I was not aware of this post. I guess that my post may be viewed as a duplicate. (The only thing my post may add is the comparison to pgfplots, which one may expect to behave the same as Ti*k*Z concerning the parsing of functions. Yet this is not a big deal.)

Comment: It's quite unfortunate, this mistake is hard to avoid because of how intuitive the syntax *appears* to be. Hendrik Vogt's patch seems to still work by the way, and it looks like what is does is precisely add `(…)` around the plot variable and `{…}` around the coordinates. Not sure how comfortable I'd feel using it though…

Comment: @Circumscribe Yes, this works as far as I can tell. I actually wrote several answers where I was either using this or `\x*\x` or `pow(x,2)`. The reason why I brought this up was that the difference in behavior of Ti*k*Z and pgfplots, which keeps concerning me a bit.