# Drawing a node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to draw a [nodal curve](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MiwiZXF4Ijoic14yLTEiLCJlcXkiOiJzXjMtcyIsImNvbG9yIjoiI2ZmMDAwMCIsInNtaW4iOiItMiIsInNtYXgiOiIyIiwic3N0ZXAiOiIuMDEifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyItNi4xMiIsIjYuODgiLCItNC4wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDEiLCIzLjk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OSJdfV0-) with tikz, that is the curve parametrized by `x(t) = t^2 - 1` and `y(t) = t^3 - t`. To do this, I tried the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [style = help lines, step = 0.5] (-1, -1) grid (1, 1);
    \draw [domain = -1.2:1.2, samples=40, variable=\t] plot ({\t^2 - 1}, {\t^3 - \t});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but what I get is

[image: the supposed curve, but the second half is mirrored]

So it seems like the part in the interval `-1.2:0` is mirrored, but I don't see what went wrong.
I get the correct picture if I split the interval at 0, and use the lines

```
\draw [domain = -1.2:0, samples=40, variable=\t] plot ({-1 - \t^2}, {\t^3 - \t});
\draw [domain = 0:1.2, samples=40, variable=\t] plot ({\t^2 - 1}, {\t^3 - \t});
```

With that I get what I expect, but it fells incredibly hacky:

[image: picture of the correct curve]

What did I do wrong here? Or did I run into some bug? Note that I still use Texlive 2017, which is included with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Please add a full compileable code.

Comment: Sigh!  Use `\t*\t` and `\t*\t*\t` instead of `\t^2` and `\t^3`. Not only does it work with negative numbers, it is much faster.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks, that works! Why though? Seems strange... If you write it in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: `\t^2` is computed using `exp{2*log(\t))`.

Comment: Apparently it works with `(\t)^2`. To me this looks like if `\t` is substituted by a negative number, the sign is not squared. How is the `log` of a negative number computed?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5400 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469747. This has lead to a lot of confusion.

Comment: Wow, so essentially ["it's not a bug, it's a feature"](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/147#issuecomment-478803263).