# How to globally declare a function for PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to be able to "globally" declare a function for use in PGFplots. That is, I want to be able to declare a function a single time, and be able to use it without having to declare it on every single plot.

Here is an MWE for what I am doing now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = {func(\x) = \x^2;}]
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:1] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1em}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = {func(\x) = \x^2;}]
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:1] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Essentially the goal would be to have something like

`declare global function = {func{\x} = \x^2;}`

somewhere in the header and then be able to use func throughout. Is there any way to do this?

Note: I specifically want to do this in PGFplots so stuff in "raw" tikz is not going to be so helpful to me.

Comment: Be aware that `\x^2` might not behave as you'd expect.  For example when `\x` is `-2` then `\x^2` becomes `-2^2` which is `-4`.  If you want to have a parabola, you would have to use `(\x)^2` instead.

Comment: Or x*x, which is also much faster.

Comment: Further reading on these issues: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125896/121799.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple: add `\tikzset{declare function = {func(\x) = \x^2;}}` somewhere (not inside a group).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{declare function = {func(\x) = \x^2;}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:1] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1em}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:1] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> **However**, I advise *not* to do that unless you are absolutely sure you want to assign this name to the function ``forever and always''.

The reason is that the inverse process is much harder. To see this, consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{declare function = {func(\x) = \x^2;}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:1] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1em}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = {func(\x) = \x^2;}]
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:1] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which throws the error

> ! Package PGF Math Error: The function `func' already
>   exists.

That is, unlike ordinary pgf keys, you can *not* simply locally overwrite the function using the `declare function` key. For that reason I would recommend to keep the function definitons local, or, if you absolutely have to, give them very unique names. Of course, there is the command `\pgfmathdeclarefunction*` that allows you to overwrite definitions that you made and want to revise, see section **95 Customizing the Mathematical Engine** for more details.