# Wrong output from power operator in TikZ declare function

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

I'm using the TikZ [`declare function`](https://tikz.dev/math-algorithms#pgf./pgf/declare:function) key and getting some weird results with squaring.

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=\x*\x;}]
  \node {\pgfmathparse{f(-.5)} \pgfmathresult}; % outputs *positive* 0.25, as expected
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=\x^2;}]
  \node {\pgfmathparse{f(-.5)} \pgfmathresult}; % outputs *negative* -0.25
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This appears only to affect `\pgfmathparse` and not `\addplot`. For example, in the MWE

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=\x^2;}]
  \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1]
    \addplot {f(x)};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{f(-0.5)}
    \addplot coordinates {(-0.5,\y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: broken graph]

we can see that the point (-0.5,f(-0.5)) is not on the graph of y=f(x) which is definitely not the expected behaviour.

Comment: It is the expected output - see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125896/8650. There are several copies of this question.