# Strange sign change in math operation result with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am working on a 3d figure using pgfplots. Since I need to operate on some pre-defined functions which are **y(x) = - 1 - x** and **zed(x,y) = - x^2 - y^2**.

I want to place points using these functions so I define the variables **\xA=0, \yA=y(\xA) and \zA=zed(\xA,yA)**. The *logical result* is that the coordinates are **(0,-1,-1)**. However, **the result that I am getting is (0,-1,1)**, which is obviously wrong. For some reason, the "z" value is being returned with the opposite sign.

I have even tried loading the tikz math package but the result is the same...

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
    y(\x) = {-1 - \x };
    zed(\x,\y) = {-\x^2 - \y^2};
    }
    ]
\begin{axis}

    \addplot3[surf,domain=-1:1,y domain=-1:1, 
    ] {zed(x,y)};
    
\tikzmath{
    \x1 = 0;
    \y1 = y(\x1);
    \z1 = zed(\x1,\y1);
}

\pgfmathsetmacro\xA{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yA{y(0)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zA{zed(\xA,\yA)}

\node at (\xA,\yA,\zA) {(\xA,\yA,\zA)};
\node at (\x1,\y1,\z1) {(\x1,\y1,\z1)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives the following figure

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `zed(\x,\y) = {-(\x)^2 - (\y)^2}` (there is a duplicate somewhere. Unary `-` and exponentiation have *strange* precedences in some part of the expressions...)

Comment: @Rmano What do you mean by "unary -"? If you mean `-1*\x^2-1*\y^2`, the result is the same if I apply `-0.2*\x^2-0.3*\y^2` for example.

Comment: @Rmano Ok, I just got it that the comment was the answer... Thanks. However, it would indeed be interesting to know where is the original duplicate to get more insight. I could not find any information about this issue.

Comment: I am not sure of the internals, but when for example `\x` is `-1`, what TeX sees of `-\x^2` is `- -1 ^2`. Which if interpreted `- (-1)^2` gives a value, otherwise if interpreted as `-(-(1^2))` gives other. I *suspect* that the interpretation is not uniform in various part of the code...

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for the insight. If no duplicate is found by other members, then you could post your comments as an answer.

Comment: Here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125896/38080

Comment: @Rmano That does it.